# difference of meaning between "glad you liked" and "glad you like it"

Tags: meaning

Imagine my closest friend received a present I had sent to him by the post, he then thanked me by email and now I am writing an answer to him.

Shall I write

> Glad you **liked** it

or

> Glad you **like** it

I think the first one is better.But if I write liked, it is past tense, so for me it means that now my friend  does not like the present.

Is the use of the past only justified  because the receiving belongs now to  the past?

Comment: Notice that "like" is the second option. It's not clear which one you prefer. And you have too much verbs in your last sentence, I think that "does" is not necessary, you have to move "is" to the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Either is fine and should be well-received.

Technically, one could argue that:

- "glad you liked it" references your friend's pleasure upon receiving the present; and
- "glad you like it" references his continuing pleasure with the present.

However, if there hasn't been a long delay between his message and your reply, the delight he expressed can be considered to still be in the present.